# Динамические структуры данных  в паскале

Tags: pascal

Еще до конца не изучили, а лабу требуют! Помогите, брат решил не знаю правильно ли.

Даны  натуральное число n, символы s1 ,.., sn.  Получить последовательность символов,  содержащую только последние вхождения каждого  символа с сохранением взаимного порядка этих вхождений

```
uses crt;
const nmax=100;
type u=^real;
var x:array[1..nmax] of u;
    n,i:byte;
    p,s:u;
begin
clrscr;
randomize;
repeat
write('Размер массива от 3 до ',nmax,' n=');
readln(n);
until n in [3..nmax];
writeln('Массив:');
for i:=1 to n do
 begin
  new(x[i]);
  x[i]^:=5*random;
  write(x[i]^:0:2,' ');
 end;
writeln;
writeln;
new(p);
p^:=x[n-1]^+x[n]^+2*x[1]^;
for i:=1 to n-2 do
p^:=p^*(x[i]^+x[i+1]^+2*x[n-i+1]^);
write('Произведение=',p^:0:2);
for i:=1 to n do
dispose(x[i]);
dispose(p);
readln
end.
```

Comment: Нафига для таких простых задач динамические структуры дынных?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создать массив, где в качестве индексов будут символы. Помечаем значениями их как -1. Когда считываем символ в поле array[ch] = idx; где array - наш массив, ch - считанный символ и idx - индекс, которым он шёл по счёту. После этого, как всё считали делаем n итераций в каждой из которых проходим по нашему массиву и смотрим: есть ли что поставить на i-ый индекс или нет. Если есть, то выводим

Примерно такая реализация. Т.к. писал прямо с ходу в комментарии, возможны ошибки. Здесь учитываются только маленькие буквы английского алфавита. Для того, чтобы учитывать все символы необходимо написать a: array[char] of integer; и цикл, где встречается j переделать на j := #0 to #255

```
var
a : array ['a'..'z'] of integer;
n, i: integer;
j, ch: char;

begin
readln(n);
for j := 'a' to 'z' do a[j] := -1;
for i := 1 to n do
begin
  read(ch);
  a[ch] := i
end;
for i := 1 to n do
begin
  for j := 'a' to 'z' do
  if a[j] = i then 
  begin 
    write(j); 
    break
  end
end
end
```